# Android Fill the empty space in a layout

Tags: android, xml

My layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout 
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:background="@color/skyblue" >

        <TextView
          android:id="@+id/tvPlaceHeader"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="@string/places"
          android:layout_margin="10dp"
          android:layout_gravity="center"
          android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

      <ImageView
         android:contentDescription="@string/search"
         android:id="@+id/ivPlace"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:src="@drawable/logo" />

     <TextView
         android:contentDescription="@string/search"
         android:id="@+id/tvTrivia"
         android:textSize="14sp"
         android:textStyle="bold"
         android:layout_margin="10dp"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="@string/search" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

The screenshot:

[image]

My question is, why is it not covering the whole layout? I mean it has a white space below but I declared in my xml to have its background color as blue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this line **android:background="@color/skyblue"**  from LinearLayout and write in ScrollView

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/skyblue" 
 >
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your inner LinearLayout height

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" // CHANGED LINE
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/skyblue" >
```